# xltabular page break multiple pages

Tags: page-breaking, two-column, xltabular

as part of an article, I am translating a text from an oriental language to German. I am writing the short introductiona and then follows the text. Thus, I wanted to place it in a table with two columns and two lines. My problem: I am using xltabular and it does not make an automatic pagebreak. How can I fix it? For the oriental languages, it is important to avoid line breaks. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\keepXColumns
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

In the next lines, the text will be translated into German:

\begin{xltabular}[l]{0.75\linewidth}{@{} lX @{}}
\caption{The \texttt{xltabular} environment with \texttt{longtable} property
and left aligned by setting the optional argument.}\\[\belowcaptionskip]\hline
Arabic & German\\
\hline
Left column & At first a line with some nonsense text to show how long this line is.
The caption has the same width as the text. At first a line with some nonsense text to show how long this line is.
The caption has the same width as the text At first a line with some nonsense text to show how long this line is.
The caption has the same width as the text At first a line with some nonsense text to show how long this line is.
The caption has the same width as the text At first a line with some nonsense text to show how long this line is.
The caption has the same width as the text At first a line with some nonsense text to show how long this line is.
The caption has the same width as the text At first a line with some nonsense text to show how long this line is.
The caption has the same width as the text At first a line with some nonsense text to show how long this line is.
The caption has the same width as the textAt first a line with some nonsense text to show how long this line is.
The caption has the same width as the textAt first a line with some nonsense text to show how long this line is.
The caption has the same width as the textAt first a line with some nonsense text to show how long this line is.
The caption has the same width as the textAt first a line with some nonsense text to show how long this line is.
The caption has the same width as the textAt first a line with some nonsense text to show how long this line is.
The caption has the same width as the textAt first a line with some nonsense text to show how long this line is.
The caption has the same width as the textAt first a line with some nonsense text to show how long this line is.
The caption has the same width as the textAt first a line with some nonsense text to show how long this line is.
The caption has the same width as the textAt first a line with some nonsense text to show how long this line is.
The caption has the same width as the textAt first a line with some nonsense text to show how long this line is.
The caption has the same width as the textAt first a line with some nonsense text to show how long this line is.
The caption has the same width as the textAt first a line with some nonsense text to show how long this line is.
The caption has the same width as the textAt first a line with some nonsense text to show how long this line is.
The caption has the same width as the textAt first a line with some nonsense text to show how long this line is.
The caption has the same width as the textAt first a line with some nonsense text to show how long this line is.
The caption has the same width as the textAt first a line with some nonsense text to show how long this line is.
The caption has the same width as the textAt first a line with some nonsense text to show how long this line is.
The caption has the same width as the text\\
t\\\hline
\end{xltabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Well, `longtable` (or `xltabular` which does more or less the same) can break tables so that they can span over several pages, but it does *not* break the contents of cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is possible to split tables over several pages, you cannot split a single cell. This is due to the fact that a cell is an unbreakable box and therefore holds true for `xltabular` as well as for `longtable` and in general for every `tabular` environment.

I therefore suggest a different approach, although it comes with certain restrictions, too: You can use a `description` environment and style this according to your needs using the `enumitem` package. This way, at least the right "column" which contains the description text is breakable over several pages.

The left "column" that holds the label (which is now placed inside a `\parbox`) cannot break across pages, though. Also, if the text in the left "column" is longer than the text in the right "column", it will overlap the following row.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{translation}{description}{1}
\setlist[translation]{align=parleft, labelwidth=*, leftmargin=14em, font=\normalfont, before=\raggedright}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{translation}

    \item[\textbf{English}] \textbf{German}
    
    \item[One morning, as Gregor Samsa was waking up from anxious dreams, he discovered that in bed he had been changed into a monstrous verminous bug. He lay on his armour-hard back and saw, as he lifted his head up a little, his brown, arched abdomen divided up into rigid bow-like sections.]

    Als Gregor Samsa eines Morgens aus unruhigen Träumen erwachte, fand er sich in seinem Bett zu einem ungeheueren Ungeziefer verwandelt. Er lag auf seinem panzerartig harten Rücken und sah, wenn er den Kopf ein wenig hob, seinen gewölbten, braunen, von bogenförmigen Versteifungen geteilten Bauch, auf dessen Höhe sich die Bettdecke, zum gänzlichen Niedergleiten bereit, kaum noch erhalten konnte. Seine vielen, im Vergleich zu seinem sonstigen Umfang kläglich dünnen Beine flimmerten ihm hilflos vor den Augen.

    \item[``What's happened to me,'' he thought. It was no dream.]

    \lipsum[1-2]

\end{translation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

*Some notes:*

In case you want to use square brackets `[]` inside the argument for `\item`, you need to place the whole argument between curly braces `{}`. So, it should look like this: `\item[{something with [square] brackets}]`

If you wish to have the text in the first column centered or right aligned, you can do this by defining a new align style using `\SetLabelAlign` and then use this style with the option `align`:

```
\SetLabelAlign{parcenter}{\strut\smash{\parbox[t]\labelwidth{\centering #1}}}

\newlist{translation}{description}{1}
\setlist[translation]{align=parcenter, labelwidth=*, leftmargin=14em, font=\normalfont, before=\raggedright}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem with this solution is that I had some additions or clarifications of my translation and I had to put them in square brackets "[...]". How can this be fixed?

Comment: @into You mean that you need to use square brackets inside of `\item[]`? You should then place curly braces `{...}` around everything: `\item[{something with [square] brackets}]`.

Comment: Yes, exactly; problem solved. Next problem: How can I make the first column centered and the last one left-aligned?

Comment: @into See my edit. Remove `before=\raggedright` if you want the right column to have justified (last line left aligned) text.

Comment: Thanks again. I made a mistake: The first column should not be centered, but justified - what should be changed for that. Another question: I have several of such smaller translations and I want to know if it is possible not to standardize the measure of the leftmargin, but changed it in some cases?

Comment: @into For justified text, use `\SetLabelAlign{parjustified}{\strut\smash{\parbox[t]\labelwidth{#1}}}`. You can always overwrite the default options locally. So, you could say, for example: `\begin{translation}[leftmargin=10em]`

Comment: I have another question related to this: I really liked this solution and I am thinking about changing my other tables with 3 columns to this style. How can I have this format with 2 and 3 columns in my document?

Comment: @into I am unsure whether this set-up is really the best solution in this case. What should the other columns contain? Note that with this set-up, only the right column is really breakable across pages, while the other column is not. So, this can only work with more then two columns if you still only have one column that needs to be breakable across pages. I think, it would be best to ask a new question on this site by referring to this question.